# How to implement unit tests on IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class and a comparer for this class that implements `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }

    public Foo(int i, string s)
    {
        Int = i;
        Str = s;
    }

    private sealed class FooEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
    {
        public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
            if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
            return x.Int == y.Int && string.Equals(x.Str, y.Str);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (obj.Int * 397) ^ (obj.Str != null ? obj.Str.GetHashCode() : 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<Foo> Comparer { get; } = new FooEqualityComparer();
}
```

The two methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are used for example in `List.Except` via an instance of the comparer.

My question is: how to implement properly unit tests on this comparer? I want to detect if someone adds a public property in `Foo` without modifying the comparer, because in this case the comparer becomes invalid.

If I do something like:

```
Assert.That(new Foo(42, "answer"), Is.EqualTo(new Foo(42, "answer")));
```

This cannot detect that a new property was added, and that this property differs in the two objects.

Is there any way to do this?

If it is possible, can we add an attribute to a property to say that this property is not relevant in the comparison?

Comment: You can´t expect your comparer to compare properties it doesn´t know they exist. You have to change the comparer to also check the new properties. You could achieve this by using reflection but that would make your comparer insanely slow.

Comment: `Foo` should be immutable if you intend to use it as key in hash tables. An in that case new properties needs to be set using the ctor's paramsters, and anyone doing so would see that your test for the Comparer no longer compiles. (And hopefully update the comparer and the test).
Another easy way, just add a comment in Foo that Comparer XXX needs to be updated.

Comment: @Magnus That seems interesting, but how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the properties of the type, e.g.:

```
var knownPropNames = new string[]
{
    "Int", 
    "Str", 
};
var props = typeof(Foo).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var unknownProps = props
                    .Where(x => !knownPropNames.Contains(x.Name))
                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                    .ToArray();
// Use assertion instead of Console.WriteLine
Console.WriteLine("Unknown props: {0}", string.Join("; ", unknownProps));
```

This way, you can implement a test that fails if any properties are added. Of course, you'd have to add new properties to the array at the beginning. As using reflection is an expensive operation from a performance point of view, I'd propose to use it in the test, not in the comparer itself if you need to compare lots of objects.

Please also note the use of the `BindingFlags` parameter so you can restrict the properties to only the public ones and the ones on instance-level.

Also, you can define a custom attribute that you use to mark properties that are not relevant. For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ComparerIgnoreAttribute : Attribute {}
```

You can apply it to a property:

```
[ComparerIgnore]
public decimal Dec { get; set; }
```

In addition, you'd have to extend the code that discovers unknown properties:

```
var unknownProps = props
                    .Where(x => !knownPropNames.Contains(x.Name) 
                        && !x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComparerIgnoreAttribute)).Any())
                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I prefer your solution, because it causes no runtime overhead and tankes place only in tests.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could check all the properties you want to check in `Equals` via reflection. To filter some of them out use an attribute on those properties:

```
class Foo
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public string IgnoredProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your comparer check for that specific attribute. Afterwards compare every property that is contained in the remaining list via [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => "Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(MyAttribute));
        var equal = true;
        foreach(var p in properties)
           equal &= p.GetValue(x, null) == p.GetValue(y, null);
        return equal;
    }
}
```

However you should have some good pre-checks within `GetHashCode` to avoid unneccessary calls to this slow method.

EDIT: As you´ve mentioned ReSharper, I assume as you provide the actual properties to be validated at runtime even R# doesn´t know a good way to implement `GetHashCode`. You will need some properties that will allways be available on your type and that provide a good enough idea of what might be considered equal. All theadditional properties however should only go into the expensive `Equals`-method.

EDIT2: As mentioned in the comments doing reflection within `Equals` or even `GetHashCode` is a bad idea as it´s usually quite slow and can often be avoided. If you know the properties to be checked for eqality at compile-time you should definitly include them within those two methods as doing so gives you much more safety. When you find yourself really to need this because you have to many properties you probably have some basic problem as your class is doing too much.

Comment: I let Resharper implement the hash calculation. This should be ok.

Comment: I would strongly avoid using reflection in either Equals or GetHashCode. They are indented to be fast and that is not.

Comment: @Magnus I totally agree, however there´s no other way to dynamically check against an unknown set of properties.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I badly explained in my post. No property will be added at runtime. I only want to ensure that nobody modify this class without make some test red. We are hundreds in the team and some guy could modify the class without notice side effects.

Comment: @Boiethios If this is the case why do you expect every newly introduced property to change the equality-state of your object. It might be possible that some of your collegues introduces a new property whereby this property should not even be recogniced within any equality-check. You´d have to rely on your teammates intention if or if not they think their properties are relevant. Or are your objects just DTOs that should be completely identical?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The equality is used to check if the object must be removed and inserted in its new version in a database, or only updated. If a property is added, the table will be updated too because the object is built from database. So adding a property is a breaking change.

Comment: @Boiethios Then you might introduce some dirty-flag that determinaes if your object was modified istead of constantly checking all properties if they are still same as what you have in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can check properties count inside the comparer. Something like this:

```
private sealed class FooEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    private List<bool> comparisonResults = new List<bool>();
    private List<Func<Foo, Foo, bool>> conditions = new List<Func<Foo, Foo, bool>>{
        (x, y) => x.Int == y.Int,
        (x, y) => string.Equals(x.Str, y.Str)
    };
    private int propertiesCount = typeof(Foo)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                //.Where(someLogicToExclde(e.g attribute))
                .Count();

    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;   
        //has new property which is not presented in the conditions list and not excluded
        if (conditions.Count() != propertiesCount) return false;    

        foreach(var func in conditions)
            if(!func(x, y)) return false;//returns false on first mismatch

        return true;//only if all conditions are satisfied
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (obj.Int * 397) ^ (obj.Str != null ? obj.Str.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems good, but the `Equals` methods will be slower (and I will call this on massive amount of objects).

Comment: I have an idea how to speed it up. One minute

Comment: While your solution is very clever, the solution with no runtime overhead is better IMO. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does the unchecked keyword means ? What do you we to return in the GetHashCode function ?